# AFNetworking 3.0 AFHTTPSessionManager using NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

In AFNetworking 2.0 I am using `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. In this I can easily get NSURLRequest from following code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op;
self.fields = op.request.allHTTPHeaderFields[@"Fields"];
```

But now I am upgrading to AFNetworking 3.0 which is using `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. So, how can I achieve same result with AFHTTPSessionManager?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this ,

```
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources/123.json"];

  AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

  [manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil 
  success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
  } 
  failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Also take a look at this migration guide which will help you greatly
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide